# How to put elements from a list to a list of list in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, list, nested

I am trying to put the elements in `list2` inside each of the nested lists in `list1`. This is what I have tried so far:

```
list_1 = [[0, 1], [1, 4], [2, 3]]
list_2 = [100, 100, 100]
store_1 = []
for x in list_1:
    for y in list_2:
        x.append(y)
        store_1.append(x)
print(store_1)
```

But the output is:

```
[[0, 1, 100, 100, 100], [0, 1, 100, 100, 100], [0, 1, 100, 100, 100], [1, 4, 100, 100, 100], [1, 4, 100, 100, 100], [1, 4, 100, 100, 100], [2, 3, 100, 100, 100], [2, 3, 100, 100, 100], [2, 3, 100, 100, 100]]
```

The output should be like this:

```
[[0,1,100],[1,4,100], [2,3,100]]
```

How can i fix my code to get the desired output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `zip`

Ex:

```
list_1 = [[0, 1], [1, 4], [2, 3]]
list_2 = [100, 100, 100]
store_1 = [x + [y] for x, y in zip(list_1, list_2)]
print(store_1)
```

**Output:**

```
[[0, 1, 100], [1, 4, 100], [2, 3, 100]]
```

Comment: This'll mutate `list_1`... I suspect the OP is after `store_1 = [[*l1, l2] for l1, l2 in zip(list_1, list_2)]`

Answer (score 1):

Without using `zip`

```
list_1 = [[0, 1], [1, 4], [2, 3]]
list_2 = [100, 100, 100]
[list_1[idx] + [x] for idx, x in enumerate(list_2)]

> [[0, 1, 100], [1, 4, 100], [2, 3, 100]]
```